# Project Euler 12 (triangle numbers), solved using functools.reduce() and looping

Tags: python, programming-challenge, primes, comparative-review

I have solved [problem 12 on Project Euler website](https://projecteuler.net/problem=12), which reads:

> The sequence of triangle numbers is generated by adding the natural
>   numbers. So the 7th triangle number would be 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7
>   = 28. The first ten terms would be:
>
> 1, 3, 6, 10, 15, 21, 28, 36, 45, 55, ...
>
> Let us list the factors of the first seven triangle numbers:
>
> 1: 1
>   3: 1,3
>   6: 1,2,3,6
>   10: 1,2,5,10
>   15: 1,3,5,15
>   21: 1,3,7,21
>   28: 1,2,4,7,14,28
>
> We can see that 28 is the first triangle number to have over five
>   divisors.
>
> What is the value of the first triangle number to have over five
>   hundred divisors?

And I've solved this in two ways:

1.*functools.reduce()*

```
import math
from functools import reduce
import time

def primeFactors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = {}
    num = 0
    while i ** 2 <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            num = factors.get(i, None)
            if num is None:
                factors[i] = 1
            else:
                factors[i] = num+1 
    if n > 1:
        num = factors.get(n, None)
        if num is None:
            factors[n] = 1
        else:
            factors[n] = num+1
    return factors

start_time = time.time()
numOfDivisors = 500
n = 2

while True:
    t = int(n*(n+1)/2)
    factors = primeFactors(t).values()

    if reduce(lambda x, y: x*y, [t+1 for t in factors]) >= numOfDivisors:
        print(t)
        break
    else:
        n += 1

print("----%s seconds ----" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

2.*for-loop*

```
import math
import time

def primeFactors(n):
    i = 2
    factors = {}
    num = 0
    while i ** 2 <= n:
        if n % i:
            i += 1
        else:
            n //= i
            num = factors.get(i, None)
            if num is None:
                factors[i] = 1
            else:
                factors[i] = num+1 
    if n > 1:
        num = factors.get(n, None)
        if num is None:
            factors[n] = 1
        else:
            factors[n] = num+1
    return factors

start_time = time.time()
numOfDivisors = 500
n = 2

while True:
    t = int(n*(n+1)/2)
    factors = primeFactors(t).values()

    k = 1
    for i in factors:
        k *= (i+1)

    if k >= numOfDivisors:
        print(t)
        break
    else:
        n += 1

print("----%s seconds ----" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

I tested out which one was faster, found that there was a fine line only:

`1.670 secs` and `1.678 secs`

I attempted to calculate the average computing time by making the given number bigger from 500 to 1000, repeating this process 10 times.

But both solutions were done almost simultaneously:

1. *functools.reduce*

   `[13.616845607757568, 13.67394757270813, 13.623621225357056, 13.596383094787598, 13.657264471054077, 13.694176197052002, 13.669324398040771, 13.65349006652832, 13.66620421409607, 13.57088851928711, 13.686619901657104]`
2. *for-loop*

   `[13.56181812286377, 13.686477422714233, 13.548126935958862, 13.565587759017944, 13.562162637710571, 13.556873798370361, 13.562631845474243, 13.572312593460083, 13.57419729232788, 13.567578315734863, 13.611796617507935]`

**Question**: Are there any insignificant or significant differences between the two from a practical view and in a normal case, Or is this just a matter of behavior of two functions to use?

Comment: Your solutions give `253` as the answer. A number that is smaller than 500 cannot possibly have over 500 divisors.

Comment: @200_success There was incorrect indentation in `primeFactors` function. I fixed this. And.. thanks for your revision.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](https://www.python.org/doc/essays/list2str/)'s an in-depth view from BDFL.

`reduce` should be faster, especially if you supply it with function that is written in C . Try replacing your multiplication lambda with [`operator.mul`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html) and see if anything changes.

There *is* a matter of style which of two functions to prefer, because more complex tasks would require more complex lambdas and the whole thing would be less comprehensible than for-loop. Thus, use of `reduce` was discouraged and it was moved into `functools`.

On the other hand, for less complicated tasks there are such things as `sum`, `all` and `any`. Latter two also short-circuit, whereas `reduce` does not.

Comment: Could you source where it was said that `reduce` was removed as it didn't short-circuit? [I always thought it was due to readability concerns](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-3000/2006-April/001030.html)

Comment: Very funny. 123

Comment: your source seems very helpful for me. Thanks!